# What is Type<Type> called?

Tags: java, generics

What is

```
Type<Type> type;
```

called (opposed to)

```
Type type;
```

You know, where you put the angle brackets around the type? I use this a lot, but don't know the name - it's bugging me. It's very hard to search for - Google ignores the `<>` characters.

(note: this is Java)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generics! :)

Answer (score 9):

Generics: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html

Answer (score 3):

[Generics or parameterized types.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming)

(Hey, two people already posted the same thing as each other and both got ~3 upvotes.  I'm just looking for a share of the love.)

Comment: Why are there 2 different names?

Comment: Because I've seen both in usage, and I thought it might be helpful for the OP to know that they both mean the same thing.  I also considered adding "templated types" since some C++ programmers call Java Generics that, but I decided not to because the differences (especially in how it's implemented) are significant.