# What is List<?> in Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Type<Type> called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286005/what-is-typetype-called)
>   [What does List<?> mean in java generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844770/what-does-list-mean-in-java-generics)

```
package com.xyz.pckgeName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Statement {

// public String
public String status;
public String user_id;
public String name;
public String available_balance;
public String current_balance;
public String credit_card_type;
public String bank_id;
public List<Statements> statements = new ArrayList<Statement.Statements>();

public class Statements {
    public String month;
    public String account_id;
    public String user_id;
    public String id;
    public List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
}
}
```

Can anyone explain me what these two statements mean

```
public List<Statements> statements = new ArrayList<Statement.Statements>();

public List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: I added the "generics" tag for you. I know you didn't know about it, but I did. Hopefully it will lead to some trivially similar related questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844770/what-does-list-mean-in-java-generics , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218216/in-java-what-does-it-mean-when-a-type-is-followed-by-angle-brackets-as-in-list

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) in java

`List<?>` is essentially translated as a *"List of unknowns"*, i.e., a list of unknown types. The `?` is known as a [Wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) (which essentially means *unknown*).

---

```
public List<Statements> statements = new ArrayList<Statement.Statements>();
```

This essentially creates a `List` that only accepts `Statement.Statements`. Anything outside of `Statement.Statements` that you want to add to `statements` will create a compilation error. The same applies to `public List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();`. This means that the `List` is [bounded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html) to a type `Statement.Statements` (on `statements` variable).

Comment: Can we simply say that it stores objects of Statements which in nested class in Statement?'

Comment: Thanks for reply, let me read documentation and make some examples, I am upvoting and accepting answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is the use of generics. You are declaring a List of either Statement objects or Transaction objects.

Check out wikipedia for more info

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 2):

You should read about [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) to understand this . List is a raw type which could be the list of Objects such as Strings,Wrappers and user defined objects .

```
public List<Statements> statements = new ArrayList<Statement.Statements>();
```

The above code says that statements is the reference to the ArrayList of Statement Objects . It does specifies that list would contain Statements objects which is inner class to the Statement class.

`List<?>` is used to say the list of unknown type.

Answer (score 1):

The `statements` List can hold only  `Statements` object. It is called Generics. Check this for sample programs.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Asimplegenericclass.htm