# What's the difference Between List and List<?>?

Tags: java

I'm taking here about Iterators, Lists, etc.. , when trying to declare it without assigning parameters:

```
List mylist;
Iterator mykey;
```

I got the warning:

```
List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized
```

but when change it to:

```
List <?> mylist;
Iterator <?> mykey;
```

the warning disappears like if I solve the problem which didn't happen as I'm didn't assign a Solid Parameter to it. So, what makes the Compiler ignores the warning when giving it that **generic** parameter? and why Java don't consider that not giving it a parameter is like giving it a generic parameter as in both cases I can completing the initialization process with the same RHS.

Comment: ? means a `List` or rather `Type` of *unknowns*, check this out too: [What is List<?>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664932/what-is-list-in-java-android)

Comment: See this: [What is the difference between the unbounded wildcard parameterized type and the raw type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ303)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844770/what-does-list-mean-in-java-generics

Comment: I understand that there's may be some duplicates but I tried to search before and got nothing as I didn't know that it's type name in `wildcard`

Comment: thanks for all these useful links