# Referring a class on a list newbie confusion

Tags: java, android

I was studying livewallpaper in this [site](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html). However something there is something that i dont understand.

Example in the code of the tutorial there a class named MyPoint

```
public class MyPoint {
  String text;
  private int x;
  private int y;

  public MyPoint(String text, int x, int y) {
    this.text = text;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

then after he created a MyWallpaperService class. Inside of that class there is a line of code like this

```
 private List<MyPoint> circles;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private int width;
    int height;
    private boolean visible = true;
    private int maxNumber;
    private boolean touchEnabled;

public MyWallpaperEngine() {
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
      .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyWallpaperService.this);
  maxNumber = Integer
      .valueOf(prefs.getString("numberOfCircles", "4"));
  touchEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("touch", false);
  circles = new ArrayList<MyPoint>();
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);
  handler.post(drawRunner);
}
```

You can see the part of code has

```
private List<MyPoint> circles;
```

This is the part that i dont understand? What is happening in here? What will `List<MyPoint>` pass in the circles? Anyone knows what to call this? is this list reffering to a class? Cause im not sure on my title. Thank you..

Comment: The angle brackets <> are [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) in Java. It is creating a list that can only hold `MyPoint` objects

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286005/what-is-typetype-called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private List<MyPoint> circles;
```

States that circles is a `List` of type `MyPoint`, (ie. it will hold **objects of type MyPoint**).

```
circles = new ArrayList<MyPoint>();
```

Now in the above line you are assigning the ArrayList object of type MyPoint to the Object Reference Variable of type List.

This is called as Interface Polymorphism.

`List` is an **Interface**, where as `ArrayList` a **Concrete Class** which **implements List.**

**Eg:**

```
public class Dog{

   private String dName;
   priavet int dAge;

   public Dog(String dName, String dAge){

      this.dName = dName;
      this.dAge = dAge;


   }



   public String getDName(){

        return this.dName;

   }

   public String getDName(){

        return this.dAge;

   }

}


public class Test{


 public static void main(String[] args){

     List<Dog> dAList = new ArrayList<Dog>();

     dAList.add(new Dog("Tommy",5));
     dAList.add(new Dog("Stark",2));

     for(Dog d : dAList){   // Iterating over the List of Dog objects

           System.out.println(d.getDName());
           System.out.println(d.getDAge());

         }


     }



}
```

Comment: Does that mean that it will be a list of mypoint? Do you have a very simple tutorial how this works? Thank you

Comment: Fine.... i will write a small snippet of code for you.... just see my edits...after 2 min

Answer (score 1):

Its creating a list of objects. A List of MyPoint type objects
MyPoints in your case refers to the (x,y) coordinates of the circle(as you referred)

Answer (score 1):

The `List<MyPoint>` object is, as the name suggests, a list of `MyPoint` instances which, judging from the code, represent the centers of your circles. The `private` identifier simply indicates that it cannot be accessed from outside of the class in which it is defined.